# Unable to deploy profile to JBoss Fuse 6.1 using fabric8:deploy

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse, fabric8

I am trying to deploy a simple Camel route to my local instance of JBoss Fuse 6.1 (GA release).  I am trying to use the fabric8-maven-plugin to do so, but everytime I run fabric8:deploy, I receive the following error

Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.0.0.redhat-379:deploy (default-cli) on project filemover: Error executing: IO-Error while contacting the server: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Here is my current plugin-definition from my pom file

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
<artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.redhat-379</version>
<configuration>
    <profile>sample-filemover</profile>
    <parentProfiles>feature-camel</parentProfiles>
    <features>mq-fabric-camel</features>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

My ~/.m2/user/settings.xml file contains the following server definition

```
<server>
    <id>fabric8.upload.repo</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

And I am executing the following mvn command

```
mvn fabric8:deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

(I realize I am skipping the tests, but I am trying to just deploy a profile at this time)

I can log onto the management console just fine and can see the root container no problem.  Have I missed something in the configuration of Fuse to enable this?

Comment: You can try mvn fabric8:deploy -X to include more details. Maybe there is a hint what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just spend some hours in the same problem.
Just change the version to 1.1.0.CR5 and you can deploy using mvn fabric8:deploy
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are trying on the correct server? Just put the fabric URL server where you want to deploy. I'm using that plugin version and it works correctly.

I know may be it's too late, but just for let you know, you can deploy in any server with

**mvn clean fabric8:deploy -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://localhost:8181/jolokia**

Cheers